# jsPDF com colspan no topo da tabela

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf

eu estou tentando montar um pdf baseado na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo gerear o pdf, mas sem a linha com "Info" e "Contact". É possivel gerar o pdf da mesma forma como na imagem?

Isso é o que consegui fazer até agora

```
this.pdf = function(title, table, hideInfo) { 
 var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4'), start = 65;

 doc.setFont('helvetica');
 doc.setFontSize(8);
 doc.text(title, (doc.internal.pageSize.width - 
 doc.getStringUnitWidth(title) * 8) / 2, 50);
 doc.setFontSize(6);

 doc.autoTable(table.columns, table.data, {
 startY: start,
 margin: { horizontal: 25 },
 styles: { overflow: 'linebreak', fontSize: 6, font: 'helvetica' },
 bodyStyles: { valign: 'top' },
 pageBreak: 'auto',
 theme: 'grid',
 columnWidth: 'wrap',
 headerStyles: { fillColor: [20, 167, 146] },
 drawCell: function(cell, data) {
 if (data.row.raw[0] && data.row.raw[0].toString().trim().toLowerCase() === 'total') {
  doc.setFillColor(233, 233, 233);
  doc.setFontType("bold");
 }
}}); 
doc.save(title.replace(/ /g,"_") + '.pdf');};
```

Comment: Você tá renderizando do HTML? ou você ta gerando do Angular dentro do ngfor?

Comment: Estou gerando pelo angular, eu tenho um objeto e uso o ng-repeat

Comment: experimente o plugin [AutoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)

Comment: tomasantunesw, eu já estou usando esse plugin, o que não consegui fazer até agora é adicionar os colspan no topo da tabela. Eu adicionei o código que fiz até agora.